# Plot a Taylor series using \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I have a little question: I need to create the Taylor series of funtion `f(x) = 1/(1-x)`.
I am trying to use the command `\foreach` to create the Taylor series `1+x+x^2+x^3+...` inside the environment `tikzpicture`, but I cannot because `x` is a variable.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Answer (score 4):

This plots various orders of the Taylor expansion (or geometric series).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[domain=0:1,smooth,no markers]
  \addplot[thick,color=orange,domain=0:0.9] {1/(1-x)};
  \def\myfun{1}
  \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \nn in {1,...,8}
  {\edef\myfun{\myfun+pow(x,\nn)}
   \addplot+{\myfun};
  }
 \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use the `math` library of Ti*k*Z to recursively define these objects, see the `fibonacci` example on p. 704 of pgfmanual v3.1.5.

Comment: cat: how to recusively define like this? `\def\taylor{1}
\foreach \n in {1,...,8}
{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{\n+1} 
\edef\taylor\m{\taylor\n+pow(\x,\n)}
}`
does not work

Comment: @BlackMild You need either `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` as in my answer (since definitions are local) or use the `remember` key. Since the OP asks a `pgfplots` question, I think `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` is the easier way to go.

Comment: @SC: it's good to see an update of your answer with TikZ-only solution

Comment: @BlackMild What for? Why do you think it makes sense to add a more complicated variation of that?