# Graphing Fourier series with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

im having a great difficulty representing a Fourier series with TikZ. The problem is:

> Find the Fourier series of the function: *f(x)=cos(px)*, for *p* not integer.

I found the correct result which is:

[image]

And here is the problem! I want to draw this functions for *n=1,2,4,8* with *p=8/5*. I tried to write term by term, but it does not work. My code:

---

```
\documentclass[margin=0.3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            xmin = -4, xmax = 4,
            ymin = -3, ymax = 3,
            domain = -pi :  pi,
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
            axis x line = center, 
            axis y line = center,
            every axis x label/.append style = {below},
            every axis y label/.append style = {left},
            xtick = {0, -3.14, 3.14},
            ytick = {0},
            xticklabels = {$0$, $-\pi$, $\pi$},
            ]
    
    \addplot [ultra thick,samples=300](\x,{cos(1.6*\x r)});
    
    \addplot [samples=300, red](\x,{
    ((1)/(1.6*pi))*sin(1.6*pi) - 
    ((2*1.6)/pi)*sin(1.6*pi)*((cos(1*\x r)*(-1)^1)/(1^2-1.6^2))
    });
    
    \addplot [samples=300, blue](\x,{
    ((1)/(1.6*pi))*sin(1.6*pi) - 
    ((2*1.6)/pi)*sin(1.6*pi)*((cos(1*\x r)*(-1)^1)/(1^2-1.6^2)) - 
    ((2*1.6)/pi)*sin(1.6*pi)*((cos(2*\x r)*(-1)^2)/(2^2-1.6^2))
    });
    
    \addplot [samples=300, green](\x,{
    ((1)/(1.6*pi))*sin(1.6*pi) - 
    ((2*1.6)/pi)*sin(1.6*pi)*((cos(1*\x r)*(-1)^1)/(1^2-1.6^2)) - 
    ((2*1.6)/pi)*sin(1.6*pi)*((cos(2*\x r)*(-1)^2)/(2^2-1.6^2)) - 
    ((2*1.6)/pi)*sin(1.6*pi)*((cos(3*\x r)*(-1)^3)/(3^2-1.6^2)) - 
    ((2*1.6)/pi)*sin(1.6*pi)*((cos(4*\x r)*(-1)^4)/(4^2-1.6^2))
    });
    
    \addplot [samples=300, orange](\x,{
    ((1)/(1.6*pi))*sin(1.6*pi) - 
    ((2*1.6)/pi)*sin(1.6*pi)*((cos(1*\x r)*(-1)^1)/(1^2-1.6^2)) - 
    ((2*1.6)/pi)*sin(1.6*pi)*((cos(2*\x r)*(-1)^2)/(2^2-1.6^2)) - 
    ((2*1.6)/pi)*sin(1.6*pi)*((cos(3*\x r)*(-1)^3)/(3^2-1.6^2)) - 
    ((2*1.6)/pi)*sin(1.6*pi)*((cos(4*\x r)*(-1)^4)/(4^2-1.6^2)) - 
    ((2*1.6)/pi)*sin(1.6*pi)*((cos(5*\x r)*(-1)^5)/(5^2-1.6^2)) - 
    ((2*1.6)/pi)*sin(1.6*pi)*((cos(6*\x r)*(-1)^6)/(6^2-1.6^2)) - 
    ((2*1.6)/pi)*sin(1.6*pi)*((cos(7*\x r)*(-1)^7)/(7^2-1.6^2)) - 
    ((2*1.6)/pi)*sin(1.6*pi)*((cos(8*\x r)*(-1)^8)/(8^2-1.6^2))
    });
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

[image]

And that certainly doesn't converge to *cos(1.6x)*. I tried to make this with Geogebra, and it worked:
[image]

If somone can help me, i appreciciate it!

Comment: You may already have the answer, actually. You're being inconsistent with the trigonometric functions, in some of them you've used the `r` suffix to indicate radians, in others not. (The `pgf` trig functions assume degrees.)

Comment: a related link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526433/plot-a-taylor-series-using-foreach